# C# : DLLImport - DLL Not Found exception

Tags: c#, c++, gcc, dllimport

Suppose I want to call c++ functions from a c# code, I am having the following problem:

Case 1:

```
class abc
{
private :
    int a ;

public :
    int  getValue()
    {
        return 100;
    }
};

int GetCounter()
{
    abc* p = new abc();

    int i = p->getValue();
    return i;
}
```

This case when calling the function from C# throws me a DLL not found exception.

Case 2:

```
int GetCounter()
{
    int i = 333;
    return i;
}
```

The case when calling the function from C# works just fine.

Any ideas why? How can I fix it?

Comment: are you calling it as  as native dll  with importdll or ? ..try C++/CLI

Comment: You'll have to copy the DLL into the build folder of your C# project so it can be found.  Easiest done by adding the DLL to your project and set its Copy to Output Directory to "Copy if newer".  Do beware that interop should only be attempted if the native code is reliable.  Your current version is not, it leaks memory.

Answer (score 0):

use this sample  Line of code in CPP Project (MathFuncsDll.h)

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) double Add(double a, double b);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) double Sub(double a, double b);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) double Mul(double a, double b);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) double Div(double a, double b);
```

in C# Code use like this

```
 [DllImport("MathFuncs.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
 public static extern Double Add(Double a, Double b);

 [DllImport("MathFuncs.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
 public static extern Double Mul(Double a, Double b);

 [DllImport("MathFuncs.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
 public static extern Double Sub(Double a, Double b);

 [DllImport("MathFuncs.dll",CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
 public static extern Double Div(Double a, Double b);

 [DllImport("MathFuncs.dll",CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
 public static extern Double Bat(Double a, Double b);
```

Comment: I also struggle for this question for weeks, Now it Works for me.. Please let me know I can help you

Comment: Hi ,  so its  : 

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int  GetCounter()
{
    abc* p = new abc();

  int i = p->getValue();

   return i;
}

correct ?

Actually its a gcc c++ code so the __declspec(dllexport) should be changed to something simillar i guess , i am using this in Xamarin studio (for android) NDK,i know that for a regular C# ( visual studio) it wont work .

Comment: I donno about the C++ coding, am just create a sample C++ in VS 2010 with these Code, My intention is to access the Methods in C#. It working fine with this code